# How to set an optionmenu with a button click tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to make a page that has a refresh button on that will reset all the widgets back to what they were originally.  The entry widgets are fine, however, I have an optionmenu that starts off with some text already selected. If someone changes this option, then hits the reset button, how do I change it back?

```
genderList = ["Gender", "Male", "Female", "Other"]
genderVar = tk.StringVar()
genderVar.set(genderList[0])
genderO = tk.OptionMenu(self, genderVar, *genderList)
genderO.config(width = 8)
genderO.pack()
```

Comment: `genderVar.set(None)` Read up on [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had your own answer in your code already (line 3) (:
You can make a function that is called when the reset button is hit, which will reset genderVar to genderList[0]. This is what it will look like: (Keep in mind I changed the name of the window to Root for testing purposes)

```
def reset():
    global genderVar
    genderVar.set(genderList[0])

root=tk.Tk()

genderList = ["Gender", "Male", "Female", "Other"]
genderVar = tk.StringVar()
genderVar.set(genderList[0])
genderO = tk.OptionMenu(root, genderVar, *genderList)
genderO.config(width = 8)
genderO.pack()

tk.Button(root,text="Reset",command=reset).pack()

root.mainloop()
```